# Flask WTForm: submit button produces no error

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I've used an identical form to submit and it has worked in the past. The submit button isn't working now, so everything within the POST and validate loop is not being executed.

This is a single page webapp. This form should take 7 fields and write to the db. The app does properly print the records (recent_data) from the db, so the connection to the db is correct.

Expected behavior: This should produce a POST-GET redirect. The submit button should trigger a POST, and it should redirect to the homepage, with the form now empty.

Current Behavior: The submit button does not do anything.

Reproduce: I think this could be reproduced with the plain boilerplate flask app code added to my code here.

Debugging: There is no error displayed.

```
class ApplicationForm(FlaskForm):
    emp_length_cat_input = IntegerField(
        u'How long have you been with your employer? (1-11)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    home_status_input = IntegerField(
        u'What is your housing status? (1-Rent, 2-Other, 3-Mortgage, 4-Own)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    zip3_input = IntegerField(
        u'What is the first 3 digits of your zip code?',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    total_acc_input = IntegerField(
        u'How many accounts have you ever had in your name?',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    annual_inc_input = IntegerField(
        u'What is your annual income? (no commas)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    dti_input = IntegerField(
        u'What is your debt-to-income ratio? (round to 2 decimals)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    descr_input = StringField(
        u'Why do you need this loan? (enter text)',
        validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    # Set form
    form = ApplicationForm(request.form)
    # Form submission
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
        session['emp_length_cat_input'] = form.emp_length_cat_input.data
        session['home_status_input'] = form.home_status_input.data
        session['zip3_input'] = form.zip3_input.data
        session['total_acc_input'] = form.total_acc_input.data
        session['annual_inc_input'] = form.annual_inc_input.data
        session['dti_input'] = form.dti_input.data
        session['descr_input'] = form.descr_input.data
        with db.connect() as conn:
            conn.execute(
                """INSERT INTO
                    loans_tbl (
                        emp_length_cat,
                        home_status,
                        zip3,
                        total_acc
                        annual_inc,
                        dti,
                        descr)
                VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
                (emp_length_cat_input, home_status_input, zip3_input,
                 total_acc_input, annual_inc_input, dti_input, descr_input)
            )
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Thanks for applying')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html',
                           form=form,
                           emp_length_cat_input=session.get('emp_length_cat_input'),
                           home_status_input=session.get('home_status_input'),
                           zip3_input=session.get('zip3_input'),
                           total_acc_input=session.get('total_acc_input'),
                           annual_inc_input=session.get('annual_inc_input'),
                           dti_input=session.get('dti_input'),
                           descr_input=session.get('descr_input')
                           )
```

```
<form method="POST" action="" novalidate>
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                {{ form.emp_length_cat_input.label }} {{ form.emp_length_cat_input(id='emp_length_cat') }} </br>
                {{ form.home_status_input.label }} {{ form.home_status_input(id='home_status') }} </br>
                {{ form.zip3_input.label }} {{ form.zip3_input(id='zip3') }} </br>
                {{ form.total_acc_input.label }} {{ form.total_acc_input(id='total_acc') }} </br>
                {{ form.annual_inc_input.label }} {{ form.annual_inc_input(id='annual_inc') }} </br>
                {{ form.dti_input.label }} {{ form.dti_input(id='dti') }} </br>
                {{ form.descr_input.label }} {{ form.descr_input(id='descr') }} </br>
                {{ form.submit() }}
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the type of the button. I solved the problem like this

```
class ApplicationForm(FlaskForm):
    ...
    submit = SubmitField(
                    'Submit',
                     render_kw={'type':'submit'})
```

And you need to fix the action path

```
<form method="POST" action="/">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use form as a POST method you can simply put a button within your form inside your template to submit to form, and that should send a POST request which will be your form submitted.

```
<form method="post">
    ...
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I believe something was wrong with my submit button. I used `{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}` to render the form and it worked! Thank you.